# Is it possible to detect if other iOS apps opened before?

Tags: ios7

I've tried to find an answer but there's only way that can check if the app itself has ever opened before.

I wonder if it's possible to check a user's for an external iOS app that has opened within a period of time?

I wanna make an app that can check if the user opened a certain app, for example used Facebook on their iPhone.

Is it possible? Please provide code that can help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, there is no public API that supports this.

Comment: you can detect only installed apps in iPhone but you can't check apps history.